# Dual pivot quicksort in face of expensive swaps

Tags: algorithms, sorting, benchmarking

*I was told this is better place to ask this*
**TLDR**
Has anyone tested dual pivot quicksort performance with expensive-to-swap elements? It seems that in this case, it should massively underperform compared to standard quicksort.

And yes, I know about [Cycle Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort) (if it is only the original array that is expensive to modify) and that I could use indices/pointers inside the array, sort them and then swap them into their correct place.

However, the first is completely out of the question (Quadratic average case is just not good enough) and the second is unsuitable for implementation of general case sort. (It imposes both performance and memory consumption overhead even in cases where it is better and faster to work with the original array).

**Backstory**
Inspired by recent "question" [on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c), I decided to go and implement non trivial versions of given sorts ([introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) with [3-way partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem), median of 3 pivot selection, small block insertion sort etc).

During some research I also came upon dual pivot quicksort, [which is the current implementation of quicksort in Java standard library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])). Generally it claims that it is always at least as good as standard quicksort, and empirical testing seemed to support it. (Which is the reason it is the current implementation.)

However, it seems that no STL implementation uses dual pivot quicksort for the quicksort phase of introsort, which made me wonder why. After more research I found [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0988.pdf). It says that while dual pivot quicksort performs on average 5% less comparisons, it performs significantly more swaps. (Approximately 80% more) Obviously, since Java has only primitives and reference types, swapping is always cheap. (Even so, it uses this sort only for primitives, because it is not stable)

It also seems that at least part of the advantage of dual pivot quicksort is in its improved cache behaviour (Because it divides into smaller subarray that can fit into cache faster).

So I wanted to see whether someone already tested standard quicksort vs dual pivot quicksort when elements are expensive to swap and has the numbers (and possibly source) lying around, or whether I will have to test this myself.

Comment: with the move semantics available in C++11 the swap's cost should be alleviated

Comment: ...indeed. And even with old C++, if I know that swaps are going to be expensive, I think I'd usually sort using pointers in the container (although that incurs its own overhead). This is a cool question, but is there a specific use case that would make using pointers be a bad thing?

Comment: @JTrana In general, you do not know whether swap will, or will not be expensive, especially compared to comparisons. The question also could be rephrased as "If you have C++ value semantics (so your swaps can be nontrivial), is dual pivot quicksort still better sort for general case?" or "Would current `std::sort` be better of with dual pivot quicksort as the usual case?". The reason why you cannot (well, really should not) make general sort always start with indices/pointers is hopefully clear. (I think I will have to rephrase the question a bit.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Has anyone tested dual pivot quicksort performance with expensive-to-swap elements? It seems that in this case, it should massively underperform compared to standard quicksort.

...

> During some research I also came upon dual pivot quicksort, which is the current implementation of quicksort in Java standard library. Generally it claims that it is always at least as good as standard quicksort, and empirical testing seemed to support it. (Which is the reason it is the current implementation.)

Be careful interpreting these claims.  Many times, the comparison is against a "strawman" single-pivot quicksort implementation (usually called ''classic'' (or as you say, ''standard'') quicksort) which uses a random pivot.  This is sometimes also disguised by using unusual notation.  E.g. reporting 2 N ln N comparisons for "single-pivot" quicksort.  That translates to 1.386 N log (base 2) N comparisons, which is characteristic of selecting a single random element as the pivot.  Random pivot selection not only has poor performance (even the **worst** performing single-pivot quicksort implementation of qsort in widespread use is closer to 1.15 N log (base 2) N comparisons), but it leads to difficult-to-maintain code (you want to replicate a bug; what implementation of random number generation was used, and what was its state at the time the bug happened?).

> However, it seems that no STL implementation uses dual pivot quicksort for the quicksort phase of introsort, which made me wonder why. After more research I found this paper. It says that while dual pivot quicksort performs on average 5% less comparisons, it performs significantly more swaps. (Approximately 80% more) Obviously, since Java has only primitives and reference types, swapping is always cheap. (Even so, it uses this sort only for primitives, because it is not stable)

Again, be careful with these comparisons.  "5% less" **under what specific conditions**?  Under the best possible conditions (zero-cost, "perfect" pivot (median for single-pivot, tertiles for dual-pivot)) and uniformly-distributed random input, dual-pivot quicksort will use more than 5% **more** comparisons than single-pivot quicksort (5/3 N log (base 3) N ~~ 1.052 N log (base 2) N vs. 1 N log (base 2) N.  Swapping also depends on the implementation.  Single-pivot quicksort (conditions as specified above) is expected to use 0.25 N log (base 2) N swaps if implemented efficiently.  A dual-pivot implementation could theoretically achieve 1/3 N log (base 3) N ~~ 0.21 N log (base 2) N swaps (16% less), but it requires a great deal of bookkeeping; more typical would be 0.28 N log (base 2) N (12% more).  Note that there are many low-cost, highly-effective ways to approximate the median (i.e. pseudomedian) for single-pivot quicksort.  Not so much for tertiles.

One probably wouldn't want to use Musser introsort (recursion depth limit) with a multi-pivot scheme.  Recursion depth isn't well defined in such a case (consider that dual-pivot can behave as single-pivot if the two pivots happen to have close values, so would you compare to some multiple of the base 2 or the base 3 logarithm of array size?).  Valois introsort (randomly shuffling elements) has other issues (see above re. replicating bugs).

> It also seems that at least part of the advantage of dual pivot quicksort is in its improved cache behaviour (Because it divides into smaller subarray that can fit into cache faster).

That has been conjectured, but not definitively demonstrated.  It may be a red herring; quicksort is mostly cache-oblivious as accesses tend to be sequential.

> So I wanted to see whether someone already tested standard quicksort vs dual pivot quicksort when elements are expensive to swap and has the numbers (and possibly source) lying around, or whether I will have to test this myself.

There's code (in C) including a testing framework at https://github.com/brucelilly/quickselect and multi-pivot issues are discussed in some detail in https://github.com/brucelilly/quickselect/blob/master/lib/libmedian/doc/pub/generic/paper.pdf.  The code includes two dual-pivot implementations and many single-pivot implementations.  A highly-tuned dual-pivot implementation indeed is a bit more than 1.052 N log N comparisons asymptotically, and several single-pivot implementations are lower, closer to 1 N log N comparisons (the paper includes several performance graphs).  I haven't attempted to minimize the swaps in the dual-pivot code; the necessary bookkeeping is really onerous, and as comparisons outnumber swaps, swaps would have to be *really* expensive to be a factor, and in such a case one would probably use indirection (rearranging pointers to data).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is probably not, because it's reasonably obvious that it wouldn't matter except in rare cases.

Assume that the reason that swaps are expensive is that you are sorting objects that are large, contained in a database or accessed through an API. Regardless, those objects have keys and (by your statement) keys carry enough information that they can be compared cheaply.

Simply ensure that each key contains a reference to the underlying object. If necessary attach a pointer or index to each key. Then sort by any available method -- it obviously doesn't matter because the swaps are the expensive part.

Now perform a chase-your-tail swap on the sorted data. Start with the first key, swap it into the first position, swap the object that was there into its position and so on. You will have performed exactly the minimum number of swaps required to sort the data.

In other words, for expensive swaps there is a simple algorithm that ensures making the minimum swaps, that works regardless of sort algorithm. The only sort algorithms we care about to analyse are the ones where comparisons are expensive.

Comment: I expected as much, but it still interests me, because as far I could see, no STL implementation uses dual pivot quicksort, and I wondered whether that has to do with swapping not being completely trivial in C++, compared to Java, and having to select a good trade-off across many cases.

Comment: No, I just think it's the conservative call. Dual pivot is not backed up by enough research yet.

Comment: Ok. +1'd your answer, I will have to mule it over a bit before accepting.